# Splitting Dataset into Deciles in R

Tags: r

I am having troubling making decile portfolio.
[This is my dataset: X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNZaY.png)
Row represents 1 fiscal period and Column represents corporates.

I tried to get every quantile values in each periods.

```
 Decile_X <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 11, ncol = 56))
   for(i in 1:56){
    Decile_X[,i]<-as.numeric(quantile(X[i,], prob = seq(0, 1,length = 11), 
type = 5, na.rm=T))}
```

which yields this 
[Result of quantiles in each periods, column represents periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZKQu.png)

And with this results i tried to get the mean values between 0%~10%, 10%~20% ... 90%~100% in X dataset in each period.

```
Df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 56))
 for(i in 1:nrow(TaxExpense)){
   for(j in 1:10){
     Df[j,i] <- mean(rowMeans(X[i, which(!is.na(Decile_X[i,]) & 
       X[i,]>Decile_X[j,i] & X[i,]<=Decile_X[j+1,i])], na.rm=T))
```

But the problem is that because in some periods in Decile_X shows 0.000000000 in 40%~50%, 50%~60%, 60%~70%, so i can't split accurately.

Is there any solution to this problem?
Or is my method very inefficient to make decile portfolio?

I am new to R and tried to explain in detail.
Please help me.

Comment: You can use dplyr for splitting into deciles: mydata %>%
  mutate(quantile = ntile(x1, 10)). x1 being the column you want to use for splitting into deciles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping I understand your dilemma correctly.

Basically this is what I do for calculating the arithmetic mean within deciles. But first, I've just added some dummy data, so if you care to just copy this into your R IDE it should work as an example without having to alter it.

```
# Some dummy data
c1 <- c(1:100)
c2 <- c(301:400)
c3 <- c(101:200)
c4 <- c(201:300)
df <- cbind(c1, c2, c3, c4)
```

Here I set the number quant_n in relation to how many "partitions" there are, for lack of a better word.

```
quant_n <- 10 # 10 for decile, 4 for quartile, et cetera.
# Function for computing mean within each part of the n-tile
quantile_ave <- function(x, y = quant_n){
    z <- 1 / y
    q = quantile(x, seq(0, 1, by = z))
    cuts = cut(x, q)
    values_per_quantile = split(x, cuts)
    calc_mean = sapply(values_per_quantile, mean)
    names(calc_mean) <- NULL
    calc_mean
}

#Here we put the quantile_ave to work on the dummy data in df
results <- matrix(0L, nrow = quant_n, ncol = ncol(df)) #Matrix to overwrite with results
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    results[, i] <- quantile_ave(df[, i])
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem based on your code! Thanks again~